# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiMaterialButton'.' while suing mobile appl

Tags: maui

I am getting above error once I host my app and then trying to share a photo/file from gallery/downloads. I am using .NET Maui coding to develop.

When I doing this process, initial opened app is minimized and after sharing same app is resumed. For this I have used MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();. Once OnResume() method I got above error. And I am not using any MauiMaterialButton controls in my code. Kindly provide the solution.

Comment: Are you pressing a button to open the sharing intent? Looks like you pressed a  button, it drawn its PRESSED state, app went to background, button handler was disposed, when you returned to app the button tried to draw the UP state using the old handler that was disposed..

Comment: Where did you get this `MauiMaterialButton` from?

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?